# check is user select data from first or other columns

Tags: arrays, vba, if-statement, range

hello guys i have a question and i need a little some help

in vba i use inputbox in order for the user to select a range from a 1st column. but i want to check that the user used data only from the first column.

dim x as range
dim y as range

Set X = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter the range for X from the first column ", Type:=8)

'now i want to check if the user used the data ONLY from the first column'

Set Y=Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter the range for y from the second column ", Type:=8)

'check that the user selected data from the second column')
end sub

end sub

Comment: after Y, `If Y.Column = 1 And Y.Columns.Count = 1 And Y.Areas.Count = 1 Then: do some stuff: Else: do something else: End If`. Also, you should test each variable after the input box to check it isn't nothing (which it would be if the user pressed cancel) (e.g. `If X is Nothing Then Exit Sub`)

Comment: @Cor_Blimey  - `Range("A1:B5").Column` will still give 1...

Comment: @TimWilliams whoops. Good point. Will edit.

Comment: Do you want the user to select one value from a selected column range?? why don't you use custom messagebox with a combobox in it? the combobox's rowsource will be the column range you would like to choose.. this way you don't need to check because any value would be a valid value except null

Comment: i wannt the user to select data from the column 1 and if the user will select data from other columns too a msgbox will appear something like that

Answer (score 0):

**EDITS...**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x As Range, x2 As Range, bOK As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set x = Application.InputBox(prompt:=" Enter the range for X from the first column ", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'x will be Nothing if user cancels selection
    If Not x Is Nothing Then

        'find all cells in x which are also in ColA
        Set x2 = Application.Intersect(x, x.Parent.Columns(1))

        'x2 will be Nothing if no cells in ColA were selected
        If Not x2 Is Nothing Then
            bOK = (x2.Cells.Count = x.Cells.Count)
        End If

        If Not bOK Then
            MsgBox "Please only select cells from Column A"
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub 'user cancelled selection
    End If
    'etc...
End Sub
```

Comment: hi can i ask you somthing , the range x2 what exactly is?

Comment: `x2` is a Range which represents all of the cells in `x` *which are also in ColumnA* (the first column of x's `Parent` - ie. the containing worksheet). If `x2` has the same number of cells as `x` that must mean that all cells in `x` are in the first column.